# Setting UpdatedBy column to SUSER_SNAME() in Entity Framework 7 (SQL Server)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to set `UpdatedBy` columns in each modified entity to `SUSER_SNAME()`. I am trying to do that by overriding `SaveChanges` method as shown below.

EDIT: Using computed column (with `HasComputedColumnSql()`) for `UpdatedBy` is an option. But, that will not work for me as I need to sometimes set UpdatedBy to a value. I need `SUSER_SNAME()` to be the fallback value. Updated the code to illustrate this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(e => e.CreatedBy).HasDefaultValueSql("SUSER_SNAME()");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(e => e.UpdatedBy).HasDefaultValueSql("SUSER_SNAME()");
}

public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
    foreach (var entity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entity.Property("CreatedBy").IsModified = false;

            var currUser = GetCurrentUser();

            if (currUser != null)
            {
                entity.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = currUser;
            }
            else
            {
                // Is there a way to set CurrentValue as SUSER_SNAME()?
                entity.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = "???";
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}
```

I am not finding a way to set the `CurrentValue` to `SUSER_SNAME()` similar to the way default value is set above using `HasDefaultValueSql()`. 
 Can someone suggest a way to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's not a straight way.
You can use a sql server trigger or you can write a function to retrieve `SUSER_SNAME`.
You can insert the following function in the context just below your SaveChanges override

```
private string GetDbUser()
{
    DbConnection connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
    DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "SELECT SUSER_SNAME()";
    var connectionState = connection.State;
    if (connectionState != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Open();
    string user = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
    if (connectionState != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Close();
    return user;
}
```

Then you can use `entity.Property("UpdatedBy").CurrentValue = GetDbUser();`